# Length of a list

Tags: prolog

I am a beginner to ProLog and I am attempting the following question:

Write a predicate `len` to calculate the total duration of a list of `x`
tasks, e.g.

```
?- len([d, j, l, n], Time).

Time = 15
```

There are a set of rules which need to be followed :

```
duration(a,5).
duration(b,7).
duration(c,3).
duration(d,4).
duration(e,10).
duration(f,4).
```

I have tried the following, but there is an error message and I cannot see what I am doing wrong.

```
length([], 0).
length([X], duration(X, T), Time).

sum([],0).
sum([X|L],N) :-
    sum(L,N1),N is N1 + X.

length([X|Xs], sum([duration(Xs, Ts)], Time).
```

This is the error:  `Singleton variables: [T,Time]`
`Syntax error: Operator expected`

I want to be able to calculate the duration of several tasks in one go by inputting the tasks as a list.

I have defined the sum. What else needs to be done ?

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: please include the error message you see.

Comment: @theannouncer I have edited to include the error message

Comment: I would encourage you to try `len(Tasks, TotalTime) :- maplist(duration, Tasks, Durations), sumlist(Durations, TotalTime).`

Answer (score 0):

You seem to try to define `length` as

```
length([], 0).
```

but `length` is already defined predicate which bounds the second argument to the length of list.
You have to define `len` here.

---

This is not good.

```
length([X], duration(X, T), Time).
```

The following will be better.

```
len([X], Time) :- duration(X, Time).
```

But if you define `len([X|Xs], Time)` correctly, `len([X], Time)` becomes unnecessary.

---

I think `sum` is not necessary. Good luck.